# Use a different formula in another cell when different values from a drop down list are selected?

Tags: excel

I have two columns in excel. In each row in column A I have a drop down list where you can choose between Asset Type A and Asset Type B.

Depending on whether A or B is selected, the adjacent cell in column B should use a different formula to calculate some inputs.

How can I get the drop down list to trigger the cell next to it to use a different formula? - apart from an IF type statement of IF(A, Then this, otherwise B) I was wondering if there is a neater solution out there

Thanks

Comment: Nope, that is what the IF is for.

Comment: You can put both formulas in two other cells then use the if to return the correct answer `IF(A1 = "Asset Type A",Z1,AA1)`  Where Z1 has the formula for A and AA1 has the formula for B.